# Checking whether some sets are clubs in $ \aleph_2 $ and $ \aleph_1 $

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I'm getting acquainted with the stationary sets and clubs. I don't yet quite get everything well, so I'd appreciate some help with this question:

which of the following sets are clubs, contain a club, are stationary?

**1.** $ \{ \alpha \in  \omega_2 : \alpha \in \text{Lim} \text{ and } \text{cf}(\alpha) = \omega \}$

**2.** $ \{\alpha \in \omega_2: \exists~ \beta \text{ s.t. }\alpha = \omega + \beta \}$

**3.** $ \{ \alpha \in \omega_1 : \text{ot}(\alpha \cap \text{Lim}) = \alpha \}$

Where $ \text{cf, ot, Lim} $ denote, respectively, cofinality, order type and the class of limit ordinals.

Here are some of my thoughts:

**1.** I believe that $ \sup\limits_{\omega \leq \alpha < \omega_1} \alpha = \omega_1$ and $ \text{cf}(\alpha) = \omega $, which would mean that this set is not closed. I'm not sure, however, how to decide if it contains a club. I know that it's stationary, since for any club $ C $ we can take a strictly increasing countable sequence $ \{c_n\} \subset C $ and its limit belongs to the set.

Is this correct? As for **2** and **3** I am not really sure where to begin. I would appreciate some hints.

Comment: Hint on #2: it has a much cleaner characterization than the written one...(Secondary hint: what is $\omega+\epsilon_0$?)

Comment: I'm not sure what $\epsilon_0 $ is

Comment: In that case, $\omega + \omega^\omega$?

Comment: So by $ \epsilon_0 $ you mean the first ordinal such that $ \omega + \epsilon_0 = \omega $? And for sufficiently large $ \alpha $ it holds that $ \omega + \alpha = \alpha $?

Comment: $\epsilon_0$ has a different definition than that; it was just a random 'large countable ordinal' pulled out of a hat.  But your statement that $\omega+\alpha=\alpha$ for large ordinals is basically correct; more broadly, can you characterize all the ordinals that are of the form $\omega+\alpha$? Cantor normal form will be your friend here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument about (1) is correct, and it is really the reason that it cannot contain a club. If $\kappa>\omega$ is regular, and $D\subseteq\kappa$ is a club, then it must have limit points of every cofinality below $\kappa$ (alternatively, simply note that $\{\alpha<\omega_2\mid\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)=\omega_1\}$ is stationary, and therefore the set in (1) cannot be a club.)

In the second case, try to find out which ordinals---in general---cannot be written as $\omega+\beta$ for some $\beta$. You'll find out that there are only countably many of them.

For the third one, it is not hard to prove that the set is closed; to see it is unbounded look at [$\varepsilon_0$ and other $\varepsilon$-numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_numbers_%28mathematics%29), and try to understand whether or not they belong to this set.

Comment: But 1. contains $\{\alpha \in \omega_1 \mid Lim(\alpha)\}$, which is club in $\omega_1$.

Comment: But it's not a club in $\omega_2$, because $\omega_1<\omega_2$ and therefore it is bounded there.

Comment: Sure, it isn't club in $\omega_2$, but I thought th equestion might be a bit of a "trick" question in that it doesn't specify "club in what?".

Comment: Oh, c'mon, now you're being intentionally... a mathematician. :-P

Comment: Haha! Probably. Or pointlessly cautious, or paranoid ;)